# Why can't Item item in the for-each be resolved as a variable?

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm using a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQLhheYcnrY) to learn Minecraft. After I created a for-each loop using `java.util.ArrayList ITEMS`, I have to make an if statement, `if (item instanceof IHasModel)`. Eclipse states that the item reference in the if statement can't be resolved as a variable.

I'm using Windows 10, JDK 8u192, and Forge 14.23.5.2768. I've tried changing the name of the `net.minecraft.item.Item` in the for-each loop and then using the changed name in the if statement.

```
@SubscribeEvent
public static void onModelRegister(ModelRegistryEvent event)
{
    for(Item item : ModItems.ITEMS);
    {
        if (item instanceof IHasModel)
        {
            ((IHasModel)item).registerModels();
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting no errors, but Eclipse says that `item` cannot be resolved as a variable, everywhere in the loop.

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of the `for` line, which acts as the body of the `for` loop.

Comment: @rgettman That's a good answer, you should post it as one. :)

Comment: Which IDE are you using? A decent IDE should warn you for this.

Comment: @DevinH. It's a simple typographical error and the question should be closed as "off topic" for that reason, and it should not be answered.

Comment: Also, see [this comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQLhheYcnrY&lc=UgxjV64XG-jI2_S2uxl4AaABAg). Basically: `IHasModel` is completely and utterly unnecessary and introduces bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at your `for`-loop.

```
for(Item item : ModItems.ITEMS);
{
    if (item instanceof IHasModel)
    {
        ((IHasModel)item).registerModels();
    }
}
```

You have a semicolon(`;`) behind your first line of the for-loop which leads to it being a `no operation` (a waste of cpu time)

To clarify here is the same thing in "long" for better understanding:

```
for(Item item : ModItems.ITEMS)
{
    //nop;
}

// We are out of the for-loop scope. There is no "item" here...
{
    if (item instanceof IHasModel)
    {
        ((IHasModel)item).registerModels();
    }
}
```

To get your code working:
Remove the `;` from `for(Item item : ModItems.ITEMS);`